# VS Code UI has large characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everything Become large in my VSCode and I am stuck on this and I don't know what to do I uninstalled and reinstalled it, still no difference.

How can I solve this?

[image: pls]

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl+-` to Zoom Out
`Ctrl+=` to Zoom In